# Percentage by Row Group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I have a matrix with rows grouped by Dept (Department).  I am trying to get the actual hours / required hours percentage in a column for each row group, but I can only get the total %, not the % by group. Ex:
I should get this:

```
    Total  Employee Req Hrs Rep Hrs % Billable hrs % NonBill Hrs % Time Off %
    Dept A Total      672    680   101   575      85     140    21      8    1
    Emp1              168    170   101   150      89      50    29      0    0
    Emp2              168    165   98    120      71      20    12      8    4
    Emp3              168    175   104   155      92      20    12      0    0
    Emp4              168    170   101   150      89      50    29      0    0
    Dept B Total      420    428   102   365      87      80    19      4   .1
    Emp5              168    170   101   150      89      50    29      0    0
    Emp6               84     84   98     60      71      10    12      4    4
    Emp7              168    175   104   155      92      20    12      0    0
    G Total          1092   1108   101   940      86     190    17     12    1
```

But I get this:

```
    Total Employee Req Hrs Rep Hrs % Billable hrs % NonBill Hrs % Time Off %
    Dept A Total   1684    1675  101   1250     86     225    17     12    1
    Emp1            168    170   101   150      89      50    29      0    0
    Emp2            168    165   98    120      71      20    12      8    4
    Emp3            168    175   104   155      92      20    12      0    0
    Emp4            168    170   101   150      89      50    29      0    0
    Dept B Total   1092   1108   101   1250     86     225    17     12    1
    Emp5            168    170   101   150      89      50    29      0    0
    Emp6             84     84   98     60      71      10    12      4    4
    Emp7            168    175   104   155      92      20    12      0    0
    G Total        1092   1108   101   940      86     190    17     12    1
```

The totals are correct but the % is wrong.
I have several Datasets because the report only runs the department you are in, except for the VPs who can see all departments.
I Insert the percentage columns into the matrix and have tried several expressions with no results including:

```
=Fields!ActHrs.Value/Fields!ReqHrs.Value

=Sum(Fields!ActHrs.Value, "Ut_Query")/Sum(Fields!ReqHrs.Value, "Ut_Query")

=Sum(Fields!ActHrs.Value, "Ut_Query","Dept")/Sum(Fields!ReqHrs.Value,     
  "Ut_Query","Dept")

=Sum(Fields!ActHrs.Value,"Dept", "Ut_Query")/Sum(Fields!ReqHrs.Value, 
  "Dept","Ut_Query")
```

Plus more I can't even remember.
I tried creating new groups, and even a new matrix.

There must be a simple way to get the percentage by group but I have not found an answer on any of the interned boards.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured this out, but it doesn't make much sense. If I try:

```
=Textbox29/TextBox28 I get error messages about undefined variables.
```

If I go the the textbox properties and rename the textboxes to Act and Req and use:

```
=Act/Req  I get the right answer.
```